# javascript cookie array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

I have a problem with javascript cookies that I have been struggling with for days.
I have this function(almost the same from w3):

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{   
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x.indexOf(c_name)==0)
    {
     ar[i]=y;
     arr[i]=x;
    }
  }
}
```

Lets say that I have stored two cookies with the following names:`tablet1` and `taskt1`. When I call `getCookie('table')`, `ar.length` is 1. After that I run `getCookie('task')` and `ar.length` is 2. This causes me a lot of problems. If I put `ar=0;` at the start of the function nothing works, it's like the function just stores values every time I call it without erasing the old ones.

============================

```
var arrCookies = {};
function getCookie(c_name)
{   
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{

  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x.indexOf(c_name)==0)
    {
        arrCookies[c_name] = y;

    }
  }
}
```

when i do that the arrCookies[c_name] it does not store any values-->arrCookies[c_name].lenght is zero

=================================================
i also did

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{   
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{

  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x.indexOf(c_name)==0)
    {
        if(c_name=='table'){
            xxx[i]=x;
            xx[i]=y;
        }
        else if(c_name=='task'){
            arr[i]=x;
            ar[i]=y;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and i get the same results with my first script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using ar[i] in the loop, use ar[j] like this:

```
j=0;
for(i=0;...) {
   if(...) {
      ar[j]=...;
      j = j + 1;
   }
}
```

do you see the mistake in your code?

Comment: i did that but it does not "reset" the ar, it has no affect on the script. what i have tried 
1)ar = 0;--nothing works
2)ar = [];--does nothing
3)ar = array();--does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Use associative array instead, with key being the cookie name and value being the cookie value.

Define one array like this on top of your code:

```
var arrCookies = {};
```

Then this code in your function:

```
if (x.indexOf(c_name) == 0)
{
    arrCookies[c_name] = y;
}
```

Then to read cookie value later, e.g. cookie named "task":

```
var taskValue = arrCookies["task"];
```

Comment: i get the following error "ar[c_name] is undefined" from firebug

Comment: Because you now need to use `arrCookies` and not `ar`.

Comment: i've tried var xx = new Array(new Array(),new Array());
var xxx = new Array(new Array(),new Array()); at the top, and 
function getCookie(c_name)
{ 
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{

  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x.indexOf(c_name)==0)
    {
  if(c_name=='table'){
         xxx[0][i]=x;
   xx[0][i]=y;
  }
  else if(c_name=='task'){
         xxx[1][i]=x;
   xx[1][i]=y;
  }
    }
  }
}
and i get the same results with my previus

Comment: Why you insist on something so complicated and unreadable? Post the full code you were using that gave you "undefined" error (edit your question with it) and we'll help you fix this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard:removed extra line.